# Timeout trying to use Chrome Headless Browser print-to-pdf with Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, headless, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to create a ChromeDriver object using the ChromeOptions that will print the screen to a p.pdf. If I run the following command I'll get that:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" --headless --enable-logging --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=C:\Users\Me\Documents\google.pdf
```

Now If I try using that "print-to-pdf" argument with Selenium ChromeDriver, it times out:

```
        var fileloc = @"C:\Users\me\myFolder\doc.pdf";

        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() {
            "headless",
            "disable-gpu",
            $"print-to-pdf={fileloc} https://www.stackoverflow.com/"
        });

        var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Here is the exception error:

```
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55936/session timed out after 60 seconds.
```

The console says this:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1) on port 55936. Only local connections are allowed.
```

If I were to run it removing only the PDF argument, it seems to run just fine. Any thoughts on how to fix?